# Read input from stdin when using `pm install`

Tags: applications, installation, shell, command-line

I would like to install an application using `pm install` but not provide the APK path and rather provide application data using `stdin` as shown in the documentation below:

```
install [-rtfdgw] [-i PACKAGE] [--user USER_ID|all|current]
       [-p INHERIT_PACKAGE] [--install-location 0/1/2]
       [--install-reason 0/1/2/3/4] [--originating-uri URI]
       [--referrer URI] [--abi ABI_NAME] [--force-sdk]
       [--preload] [--instant] [--full] [--dont-kill]
       [--enable-rollback]
       [--force-uuid internal|UUID] [--pkg PACKAGE] [-S BYTES]
       [--apex] [--wait TIMEOUT]
       [PATH [SPLIT...]|-]
    Install an application.  Must provide the apk data to install, either as
    file path(s) or '-' to read from stdin.  Options are:
      -R: disallow replacement of existing application
      -t: allow test packages
      -i: specify package name of installer owning the app
      -f: install application on internal flash
      -d: allow version code downgrade (debuggable packages only)
      -p: partial application install (new split on top of existing pkg)
      -g: grant all runtime permissions
      -S: size in bytes of package, required for stdin
      --user: install under the given user.
      --dont-kill: installing a new feature split, don't kill running app
      --restrict-permissions: don't whitelist restricted permissions at install
      --originating-uri: set URI where app was downloaded from
      --referrer: set URI that instigated the install of the app
      --pkg: specify expected package name of app being installed
      --abi: override the default ABI of the platform
      --instant: cause the app to be installed as an ephemeral install app
      --full: cause the app to be installed as a non-ephemeral full app
      --install-location: force the install location:
          0=auto, 1=internal only, 2=prefer external
      --install-reason: indicates why the app is being installed:
          0=unknown, 1=admin policy, 2=device restore,
          3=device setup, 4=user request
      --force-uuid: force install on to disk volume with given UUID
      --apex: install an .apex file, not an .apk
      --wait: when performing staged install, wait TIMEOUT milliseconds
          for pre-reboot verification to complete. If TIMEOUT is not
          specified it will wait for 60000 milliseconds.
```

However, I did not understand how to exactly provide an option to use stdin. I have tried:

- `pm install -`
- `pm install '-'`
- `pm install "-"`

However, it does not prompt me for input using stdin but instead gives this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown option -
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.makeInstallParams(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2921)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1258)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:194)
        at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:26636)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:965)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:839)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:5206)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:5281)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1195)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen in the help text that you need to specify the size using `-S` parameter when using stdin?